# How to add Multi Output to DenseVariational?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-probability

I'm following this [guide](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2019/03/regression-with-probabilistic-layers-in.html) from the TensorFlow blog. But I want to output 2 values (an angle split into its sin and cos part and the standard deviation/uncertainty) instead of just 1. So I would feed in a couple of time step with that angle and I want the network to predict the next angle value.

I tried to change the units parameter of the `DenseVariatal` and the input shape. But this does not appear to be working. Could anyone tell what parameters I need to change to get a multi output? Do I need to add more layers? Code is below

```
def build(rows) -> keras.Model:
"""Builds model architecture
:return: model architecture
"""

def posterior_mean_field(kernel_size, bias_size=0, dtype=None):
    n = kernel_size + bias_size
    c = np.log(np.expm1(1.0))
    return Sequential(
        [
            VariableLayer(2 * n, dtype=dtype),
            DistributionLambda(
                lambda t: tfd.Independent(
                    tfd.Normal(
                        loc=t[..., :n], scale=1e-5 + tf.nn.softplus(c + t[..., n:])
                    ),
                    reinterpreted_batch_ndims=1,
                )
            ),
        ]
    )

def prior_trainable(kernel_size, bias_size=0, dtype=None):
    n = kernel_size + bias_size
    return Sequential(
        [
            VariableLayer(n, dtype=dtype),
            DistributionLambda(
                lambda t: tfd.Independent(
                    tfd.Normal(loc=t, scale=1), reinterpreted_batch_ndims=1
                )
            ),
        ]
    )

model = Sequential(
    [
        DenseVariational(
            1 + 1, posterior_mean_field, prior_trainable, kl_weight=1 / rows,
            input_shape=(21,)
        ),
        DistributionLambda(
            lambda t: tfd.Normal(
                loc=t[..., :1], scale=1e-3 + tf.math.softplus(0.01 * t[..., 1:])
            )
        ),
    ]
)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01), loss=nll)
return model
```

Comment: You need to use Functional API rather than Sequential API.